# JavaFX Quit menuItem

Tags: java, javafx

How can I make my program close by clicking "Quit" in Menu?
Im working with Scene Builder and with FXML so I tryed to make a method closeOPT() in main class which contains code for closing my app, but when i make an instance in controler, its not working. So now, I have no idea how to make it work.
I also tryed connecting close method with FXML id in main class but that also did not work.

```
enter code here




public class GameController {

@FXML Button b1;
@FXML Button b2;
@FXML Button b3;
@FXML Button b4;
@FXML Button b5;
@FXML Button b6;
@FXML Button b7;
@FXML Button b8;
@FXML Button b9;
@FXML GridPane gameBoard;



private boolean isFirstPlayer = true;

public void buttonClickHandler(ActionEvent evt) {

    Button clickedButton = (Button) evt.getTarget();

    String buttonLabel = clickedButton.getText();

    if("".equals(buttonLabel) && isFirstPlayer) {
        clickedButton.setText("X");
        isFirstPlayer = false;
    }
    else if("".equals(buttonLabel)&& !isFirstPlayer) {
        clickedButton.setText("O");
        isFirstPlayer = true;
    }


    find3InARow();
}

private boolean find3InARow(){
       //Row 1
       if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b2.getText() 
           && b2.getText() == b3.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b1,b2,b3);
           return true;
       }
       //Row 2
       if (""!=b4.getText() && b4.getText() == b5.getText() 
           && b5.getText() == b6.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b4,b5,b6);
           return true;
       }
       //Row 3
       if (""!=b7.getText() && b7.getText() == b8.getText() 
           && b8.getText() == b9.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b7,b8,b9);
           return true;
       }
       //Column 1
       if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b4.getText() 
           && b4.getText() == b7.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b1,b4,b7);
           return true;
       }
       //Column 2
       if (""!=b2.getText() && b2.getText() == b5.getText() 
           && b5.getText() == b8.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b2,b5,b8);
           return true;
       }
       //Column 3
       if (""!=b3.getText() && b3.getText() == b6.getText() 
           && b6.getText() == b9.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b3,b6,b9);
           return true;
       }
       //Diagonal 1
       if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b5.getText() 
           && b5.getText() == b9.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b1,b5,b9);
           return true;
       }
       //Diagonal 2
       if (""!=b3.getText() && b3.getText() == b5.getText() 
           && b5.getText() == b7.getText()){
           highlightWinningCombo(b3,b5,b7);
           return true;
       }       
       return false;
   }

private void highlightWinningCombo(Button first, Button second, Button third){
       first.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");
       second.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");
       third.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");

   }

   public void menuClickHandler(ActionEvent evt){
        MenuItem clickedMenu = (MenuItem) evt.getTarget();
        String menuLabel = clickedMenu.getText();

        if ("Play".equals(menuLabel)){
            ObservableList<Node> buttons = 
                    gameBoard.getChildren();

            buttons.forEach(btn -> {
                ((Button) btn).setText("");
                 btn.getStyleClass().remove("winning-button");
            });

            isFirstPlayer = true;
        }
        if("Quit".equals(menuLabel)) {

        }   
   } 

 }


public class Main extends Application {

Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("KrizicKruzigIgra.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,320);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void closeOPT(Stage primaryStage){
    primaryStage.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);   
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to terminate the JavaFX application from anywhere, use [`Platform.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit()).

> Causes the JavaFX application to terminate. If this method is called after the Application start method is called, then the JavaFX launcher will call the Application stop method and terminate the JavaFX application thread. The launcher thread will then shutdown. If there are no other non-daemon threads that are running, the Java VM will exit. If this method is called from the Preloader or the Application init method, then the Application stop method may not be called.
>
> This method may be called from any thread.
>
> Note: if the application is embedded in a browser, then this method may have no effect.

---

Another way is to close all the open windows as long as [`Platform.isImplicitExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isImplicitExit()) returns `true` (see [`Platform.setImplicitExit(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit(boolean))); it looks like this may have been what you were trying to do in the first place.

```
if ("Quit".equals(menuLabel)) {
    // gameBoard is one of your @FXML annotated fields
    gameBoard.getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

This only works if the `Window` that `gameBoard` belongs to is the only open `Window`.